# Can I tell Visual Studio Code that I do not want to see certain types of Problems which are actually false positives?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, false-positive

I updated to Julia 1.8.1 and noticed that now I have thousands of items in the Visual Studio Code PROBLEMS tab. Clicking on the `PROBLEMS` button I see that most of them are not due to problems in my code and some are false positive in my code. My program runs without any glitches.

These problems are in Manifest.toml:

```
Missing reference: git Julia [Ln 779, Col 1]
Missing reference: tree Julia [Ln 779, Col 5]
```

Clicking on one of these I get

```
[[deps.ATK_jll]]
deps = ["Artifacts", "Glib_jll", "JLLWrappers", "Libdl", "Pkg"]
git-tree-sha1 = "58c36d8a1beeb12d63921bcfaa674baf30a1140e"
uuid = "7b86fcea-f67b-53e1-809c-8f1719c154e8"
version = "2.36.1+0"
```

I also get problem reports related to my code every time I use the package Chain. The underscores are flagged as problems:

```
Missing reference: _ Julia [Ln 1718, Col 43]
```

In this case clicking on it does not have any effect.

Can I tell VSCode that I do not want to see reports on these types of errors?

Comment: Maybe you should report these as bugs  [here](https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues)

Answer (score 0):

I recently noticed that if I do the following all items in the PROBLEMS tag disappear, although only temporarily:

1. Open the file that has the problems.
2. Close VSCode (not just the file).
3. Reopen VSCode.

The PROBLEMS tag will eventually show similar items in another file. I have not yet figured out why that happens.